# A simple table in Jasperreports without dataset

Tags: jasper-reports

How in jasper studio to draw a simple table? The table is not dynamic. To use frame inside the frame is too crass, because of this the table is moving apart. Are there any correct ways to draw a table?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with line from Basic Elements?